# alias_module doesnot work

Tags: apache

In my httpd.conf file of my apache server(on windows7), I used ***LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so***
  And then I modified the httpd.conf with the following:

<IfModule alias_module>
        ***Alias /b /blog***
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>

After I restarted the server and type the localhost/b in my address bar,however,it did not redirect to the localhost/blog.I don't konw why.Can you help me, Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alias declarations aren't the same as redirects.

```
Alias /b /blog
```

tells Apache to make the files that exist *on your file system* under the path `/blog` (which doesn't mean much on Windows) available at the URL `http://myserver.com/b`, i.e. a request for `http://myserver.com/b/something.html` will try to return the content of the file `/blog/something.html` from your filesystem, failing if that file does not exist - the browser address bar will still say `http://myserver.com/b/something.html`.

It sounds like what you're after is

```
Redirect /b http://myserver.com/blog
```

In this case, a request for `http://myserver.com/b/something.html` will result in an HTTP redirect, the browser's address bar will change to say `http://myserver.com/blog/something.html`.

Of course, you then need to ensure that `/blog` resolves appropriately, which may require its own `Alias` if it's not under the `DocumentRoot`.

```
Alias /blog "C:/web/blog"
<Directory "C:/web/blog">
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Yeah,I kown what you mean.But actually I  have a folder named ***blog*** on my PC,I want to use alias to redirect the URL `myserver.com/b` to `myserver.com/blog`

Comment: `Alias` doesn't do redirects.  I've expanded my answer to make things clearer.